# Как создать папку с помощью Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, ос, aiogram-2.x

Уже почти неделю мучаюсь над тем как можно реализовать создание папки или файла через aiogram

**Код:**

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["CreateFile"])
async def CreateFile(CreateFile):
    await CreateFile.answer("<b>  типы\n\n\n/File Создает файл\n\n\n/Folder Создает папку</b>", parse_mode="HTML")

    @dp.message_handler(commands=["Folder"])
    async def Folder(folder):
        await folder.answer("<b>Введите путь где будет создана папка</b>", parse_mode="HTML")
        @dp.message_handler()
        async def path(path):
            await path.answer("<b>Введите имя папки</b>", parse_mode="HTML")
            @dp.message_handler()
            async def name(name):
                os.system("md " + name.text)
```

Но оно почему-то зацикливается
[image: Скрин]

---

**Если надо то вот весь код!**

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import time
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import os
import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import tkinter.messagebox
import psutil
import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab
import random

from config import TOKEN

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class FSMFolderCreate(StatesGroup):
    input_path = State()
    input_name = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["CreateFile"])
async def CreateFile(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("<b>  типы\n\n\n/File Создает файл\n\n\n/Folder Создает папку</b>", parse_mode="HTML")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["folder"])
async def cm_folder(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("<b>Введите путь где будет создана папка</b>", parse_mode="HTML")
    await FSMFolderCreate.input_path.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMFolderCreate.input_path)
async def get_path_to_folder(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("<b>Введите имя папки</b>", parse_mode="HTML")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['path'] = message.text
    await FSMFolderCreate.input_name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMFolderCreate.input_name)
async def get_name_folder(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        path_to_folder = data['path']
        name_folder = message.text
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_to_folder, name_folder))
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У меня работает.

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import config # игнорируй

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN) # делай как у себя
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

class FSMFolderCreate(StatesGroup):
    input_path = State()
    input_name = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["CreateFile"])
async def CreateFile(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("<b>  типы\n\n\n/File Создает файл\n\n\n/Folder Создает папку</b>", parse_mode="HTML")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["folder"])
async def cm_folder(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("<b>Введите путь где будет создана папка</b>", parse_mode="HTML")
    await FSMFolderCreate.input_path.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMFolderCreate.input_path)
async def get_path_to_folder(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("<b>Введите имя папки</b>", parse_mode="HTML")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['path'] = message.text
    await FSMFolderCreate.input_name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMFolderCreate.input_name)
async def get_name_folder(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        path_to_folder = data['path']
        name_folder = message.text
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_to_folder, name_folder))
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139646/discussion-on-answer-by-oleksandrigo------aiogram).

Comment: У меня запустился код все коректно но после ввода пути у меня больше не чего не появляется! Но пишет при написании команды /CreateFile

`FSMStorageWarning: You haven’t set any storage yet so no states and no data will be saved. 
You can connect MemoryStorage for debug purposes or non-essential data.
  await state.set_state(self.state)`

Comment: Так жэ все ещо нечего не пишет после введения пути

Comment: Вот скрин ошибки https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lz36mqIiJZWJJdOjPPG8E7iiIP4rmGsY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @oleksandrigo https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oR1I5zaAIPq2vggj27oXlZUAy27FFSWH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @oleksandrigo Ну блин тоже самое после введения пути ничего не выводится

Comment: @oleksandrigo А не, ошибка выводится после того как нажимаю Folder

Comment: @oleksandrigo Блиин ты лучший спасибо большое!

Comment: 0



Извини за такой тупой вопрос. Но.. как моно остановить цикл в aiogram?

Comment: @DEniss_PRogramm создавай вопрос, опиши проблему добавь код. В комментариях такое не обсуждается